# Parse Data with Many Attributes in Scala

Tags: scala, record, etl

I've been doing some self directed learning with weather data in Scala, because the data is free, big, and feeds into lots of other stuff I would like to do.  Immediately I ran into trouble with how to represent data from a text file with more than 22 columns.

What is the idiomatic way of handling data with more than 22 columns? I've been trying to read in the [NWS-USAF-NAVY station list](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/oa/climate/surfaceinventories.html) at the NOAA and they have 32 pieces of information per line.

My initial inclination was to use case classes, but the most straightforward way of defining them:

```
  /*
  first goal is to be able to read the inventory of WBAN stations from NOAA at
  ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/inventories/WBAN.TXT
  formats are listed in:
  ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/inventories/WBAN-FMT.TXT
  although I don't think that file is completely right
  */

case class WBAN(
  CoopStationID:                  Option[String],  // 01 - 06     Coop Station Id
  ClimateDivision:                Option[String],  // 08 - 09     Climate Division
  WBANStationID:                  Option[String],  // 11 - 15     WBAN Station Id
  WMOStationID:                   Option[String],  // 17 - 21     WMO Station Id
  FAALOCID:                       Option[String],  // 23 - 26     FAA LOC ID
  // and so on, for 32 elements!
```

Is not permitted because scala does not allow case classes beyond 22 items because it uses tuples to represent the data.

Nested tuples seem like a possible solution, so instead of having a field for each of the items listed by the NOAA, things like latitude, longitude, elevation, etc. could be nested:

```
  // class representing a latitude or longitude's information
case class DMS(
  Degrees:   Int,
  Minutes:   Int,
  Seconds:   Int
  )

// class combining a lat lon with elevation data
case class LatLonElevation(
  Latitude:          DMS,
  Longitude:         DMS,
  LatLonPrecision:   String,
  ElevationGround:   Option[Int],
  Elevation:         Option[Int],
  ElevationTypeCode: Option[Int]
  )
```

Or do you put it into a map with a vector in each value?

It seems like there should be a succinct way of doing this, but after implementing it I ended up repeating quite a bit of meaning in different formats, which was extremely ugly.  Is there some way to import this kind of data using SLICK or other library or will it have the same limitations as the case classes?  As an aside, is it better to use lazy val, Future, or another library to handle the connection?

Comment: Why not just make it a normal class? With so many fields you probably won't want to use it for pattern matching, so you're not losing much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have so many fields you should group them somehow.

Without grouping you can't make your class immutable, you can't use advantages of `case class` such as generated `equals` and `copy`.

It is difficult to use classes with so many fields.

In your case positions [180-219](ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/inventories/WBAN-FMT.TXT) is a single field "location" and it should be grouped in a single field. `Latitude Seconds` is completely useless without other `Latitude *` fields.

There are only 18 fields with `location` and you can reduce this number.

Natural way to group data fields is nested `case` classes.

To generate nested classes from string you could use [parsing combinator](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/combinator-parsing.html). It seems a little overkill, but you'll get a clean code structure:

```
class WbanParsers extends RegexParsers {
  def wban: Parser[Wban] = stationId ~ .... ~ latLong ~ ... ^^
    { case sid ~ ... ~ latLong ~ ... => Wban(sid, ..., latLong, ...) }
  ...
  def latLong: Parser[LatLonElevation] = dms ~ dms ~ ... ^^
    { case lat ~ long ~ ... => LatLonElevation(lat, long, ...) }
  def dms: Parser[Dms] = (" " ^^^ {Positive} | "-" ^^^ {Negative}) ~ degrees ~ minutes ~ seconds ^^
    { case sign ~ d ~ m ~ s => Dms(sign, d, m, s) }
  ...
}
```

You could create `trait` with some parsers in order to reuse them in different formats.

For instance:

```scala
class WbanParsers extends RegexParsers with LatLongParser {
  def wban: ... ~ latLonf ~ ...
  ...
}

trait LatLongParser {
  this: RegexParsers =>

  def latLong: ...
  def dms: ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: I think you might want to read the question again. Despite the title, the problem is not about parsing.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles: It's possible I did not understand the question. Could you please tell me what is wrong? It's obvious that positions [180-219](ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/inventories/WBAN-FMT.TXT) is a single field "location" and it should be grouped in a single field. So nested case classes is the way to go. The author realized it himself. "Is there some way to import this kind of data using ...?". I think the only way to import this kind of data into nested classes is to parse it.

Comment: I also don't see that your post is a possible answer to the OP's problem, since it currently is about parsing only. Your comment, however, made the connection clearer. Please improve your answer by focusing on the "nested case classes" part. The parsing part is probably helpful as well, but does not seem to be the core concern of the OP ("what could be a solution" -> nested case classes; "how to get there" -> for example, parsing via parsing combinators).

Comment: mhs took the word out of my mouth. In its updated form your answer now makes sense and is worth a +1.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles: I don't have much experience with parsers, but wikipedia that "[in] computing, a parser is one of the components in an interpreter or compiler that takes input text and builds a data structure..."  While this data structure is not very interesting and the grammar is just positional, I think it qualifies as a regular grammar (which I then lex with regular expressions).  However, like I said I don't have much experience with them and I'm mostly self taught, so this wouldn't be the first time I was wrong.

Comment: My point was just that in his initial answer, senia only advised to use parser combinators, without adressing your main problem concerning the 22 fields limit. He amended his answer to explain that the data you are parsing lends naturally to group some fields into sub-classes, therefore bringing back the individual number of fields per class) under the limit.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles: oh I see now.  Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @senia: the reason I like this answer is because it looks like a way out of the "stuttering" that I ended up with in the approach I was taking.  Nested parsers in particular have a nice correspondence with the nested case classes.  I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're describing is more general than Scala. There are two approaches to representing some data: in a [denormalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) or a [normalized form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_normalization). *Denormalized* data is flat and better suits for storage and transferring, while being harder to reason about and manage for humans. The *normalized* data is the exact opposite.

You get your data in a denormalized form. Since you're planning to use it in a high level language full of abstractions and categorizations, it is natural to normalize this data while parsing.

The general practice shows that 22 fields of case classes are far more than enough to represent any kind of data in a normalized form. Your case is not any exception, which you've already discovered yourself in your "LatLonElevation" example.

### Normalizing your data

Looking at [your data structure](ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/inventories/WBAN-FMT.TXT) it's easy to immedeately extract some subentities spanning multiple fields: *Latitude*, *Longitude*, *Elevation*. Than you can see that in fact those three are groupable themselves, since they all represent a *Location* information. Than you can look again at your structure and see that there are *FAA LOC ID*, *NWS Location Identifier*, *Country*, *State/Province Abbreviation* and *County* fields, which it all makes sense to move into the *Location* too. Doing so on you'll end up with a normalized data structure consisting of a bunch of interreferring case classes each having no more than just several fields.

```
case class Station 
  ( coopId : String,
    wbanId : String,
    wmoId : String,
    icaoId : String,
    location : Location )

case class Location
  ( faaId : String,
    nwsId : String,
    country : String,
    stateOrProvince : Option[ String ],
    county : Option[ String ],
    latitude : Latitude,
    longitude : Longitude,
    elevation : Elevation )

case class Latitude
  ( direction : LatitudeDirection.Value,
    degrees : Int,
    minutes : Int,
    seconds : Int )

object LatitudeDirection extends Enumeration {
  val North, South = Value
}

//  and so on
```

### Storing this data

Luckily for you there is a [SORM](http://sorm-framework.org) Scala DB framework which works fine with normalized data.

Comment: The distinction is helpful and I will check out SORM as well as SLICK which I mentioned above.